# C# Selenium - Enable default extensions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, selenium, google-chrome

I have a desktop application (WPF) that opens chrome browser using selenium. Whenever I load chrome externally, there are default extensions loaded.

But when I load from my application, the extensions are not available. Is it possible to have all extensions loaded when launching Chrome from my application? The extensions should not be specific.

It should all those enabled from Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome extensions are usually stored in

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<your profile>\Extensions\<extension>\<version>
```

You can iterate through all unpacked extensions and load them in selenium:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("load-extension=/path/to/extension");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```